# How to use a substitution to solve an IVP for $x<0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I attempting to solve a problem that asks you to use the substitution $t=-x$ to solve the following IVP on $(-\infty,0)$: $$x^2y''-4xy'+6y=0, y(-2)=8, y'(-2)=0$$

I'm confused about when to substitute.  If I substitute right at the beginning, then I need to solve $t^3y''+4ty'+6y=0$, resulting in $y=c_1t^{-\frac32}cos(\sqrt{15}t)+c_2t^{-\frac32}sin(\sqrt{15}t)$.  However, solving for $c_1, c_2$, using $y(2)=8, y'(2)=0$ becomes very messy.

I am supposed to instead solve with $x$ then only when solving for the constants substitute in $t$? I'm rather confused, any help pointing me in the right direction would help.

Comment: this is an example of an rulers equation. try $y = x^k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the substitution you have been given $ x=-t $ then the new ode is

> $$ t^2y''-4ty'+6y=0 $$

which has the solution ([check Cauchy-Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) )

> $$ y =c_1t^2+c_2t^3.$$

Comment: Doesn't it become $t^2y''+4ty'+6y=0$, since $x=-t$?  When I did that I got $y=c_1t^{-\frac32}cos(\sqrt{15}t)+c_2t^{-\frac32}sin(\sqrt{15}t)$.

Comment: @jdhw: No, I gave you the correct differential equation and its solution.

Comment: Can you explain why that sign stayed negative?  And why the 6 becomes a 1?  I'm rather confused.

Comment: @jdhw: It is a typo! It should be $6$. Try to work the problem of changing the variable step by step and you will get the answer

Comment: Is it since $y(x)=y(-t)=-y(t) \implies y'(t)=-y'(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

let $$x=e^t\Longrightarrow y'=\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{y}{dt},y''=\dfrac{1}{x^2}\left(\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)$$
we have
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-5\dfrac{dy}{dt}+6y$$
this equation in $y$ can be easily solve using its characteristic polynomial
$$\lambda^2-5\lambda+6=0$$
then we have
$$y(t)=c_{1}e^{2t}+c_{2}e^{3t},t=\ln{x}$$